# Compare two dataframe in pandas and edit results

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframe, df1 and df2,, df1 contains correct data that will be used to match data in df2

I want to find latitudes and longitudes in df2 that don't match the City name in df1.

Also I want to find cities in df2 that are "located" in the wrong country

[Here's df1 dataframe](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Rjsn-jotq96rYRbvlEKj8Xe7ug8BklwN/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=100970845094450129298&rtpof=true&sd=true)

id            city                lat         lng       country

1036323110  Katherine            -14.4667    132.2667     Australia

1840015979  South Pasadena        27.7526    -82.7394     United States

1124755118  Beaconsfield          45.4333     -73.8667    Canada

1250921305  Ferney-Voltaire       46.2558      6.1081     France

1156346497  Jiangshan             28.7412      118.6225   China

1231393325  Dīla                  6.4104        38.3100   Ethiopia

1192391794  Gibara                21.1072       -76.1367   Cuba

1840054954  Hampstead             42.8821       -71.1709   United States

1840005111  West Islip            40.7097        -73.2971  United States

1076327352  Paulínia              -22.7611        -47.1542  Brazil

[Here's df2 dataframe](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1KwiN5SvTCgZuN8xqdA8hAIr5wzZlvEi1/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=100970845094450129298&rtpof=true&sd=true)

id               location              city                    country

16620625-5686   45.5333, -73.2833      Saint-Basile-le-Grand   Canada

16310427-5502   52.0000, 84.9833       Belokurikha             Russia

16501010-4957   -14.4667, 136.2667     Katherine               Australia

16110430-8679   40.5626, -74.5743      Finderne                United States

16990624-4174   27.7526, -90.7394      South Pasadena          China

16790311-9092   35.98157, -160.41182   Jiangshan               United States

16650927-9151   44.7667, 39.8667       West Islip              Russia

16530328-2221   -22.8858, -48.4450     Botucatu                Brazil

16411229-7314   42.8821, -71.1709      Hampstead               United States

16060229-4175   -7.7296, 38.9500       Kibiti                  Tanzania

Here' my code so far:

`city_df = pd.merge(df1,df2,on ='city',how ='left')`

Comment: `df2` doesn't have lat and long

Comment: It has in location column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First add `lat` and `lng` columns to `df2`

```py
df2[['lat', 'lng']] = df2['location'].str.split(', ', expand=True)
df2[['lat', 'lng']] = df2[['lat', 'lng']].astype(float)
```

Then merge `df1` to `df2` based on cities

```py
city_df = pd.merge(df1[['lat', 'lng', 'city', 'country']], df2, on='city', how ='right', suffixes=('_correct', ''))
```

Find cities in df2 that are "located" in the wrong country

```py
m = ~((city_df['country_correct'] == city_df['country']) | city_df['country_correct'].isna())
```

```
print(city_df[m])

   lat_correct  lng_correct            city country_correct             id              location        country       lat        lng
4      27.7526     -82.7394  South Pasadena   United States  16990624-4174     27.7526, -90.7394          China  27.75260  -90.73940
5      28.7412     118.6225       Jiangshan           China  16790311-9092  35.98157, -160.41182  United States  35.98157 -160.41182
6      40.7097     -73.2971      West Islip   United States  16650927-9151      44.7667, 39.8667         Russia  44.76670   39.86670
```

Answer (score 0):

To compare the two data frames, it's easier to have in the first place the df1 and df2 in similar formats. For example, df1 would be like this :

```
                     lat       lng        country
city                                             
Katherine       -14.4667  132.2667      Australia
South Pasadena   27.7526  -82.7394  United States
Beaconsfield     45.4333  -73.8667         Canada
Ferney-Voltaire  46.2558    6.1081         France
Jiangshan        28.7412  118.6225          China
Dīla              6.4104   38.3100       Ethiopia
Gibara           21.1072  -76.1367           Cuba
Hampstead        42.8821  -71.1709  United States
West Islip       40.7097  -73.2971  United States
Paulínia        -22.7611  -47.1542         Brazil
```

And df2 :

```
                            country2         lng2      lat2
city                                                       
Saint-Basile-le-Grand         Canada     -73.2833   45.5333
Belokurikha                   Russia      84.9833   52.0000
Katherine                  Australia     132.2667  -14.4667
Finderne               United States     -74.5743   40.5626
South Pasadena         United States     -82.7394   27.7526
West Islip             United States   -160.41182  35.98157
Belorechensk                  Russia      39.8667   44.7667
Botucatu                      Brazil     -48.4450  -22.8858
Hampstead              United States     -71.1709   42.8821
Kibiti                      Tanzania      38.9500   -7.7296
```

Then you can use the `pd.concat` method on `axis=1` as follow :

`df3 = pd.concat([df1,df2],axis=1)` in order to get the following df :

```
                           lat       lng        country       country2         lng2      lat2
city                                                                                         
Katherine             -14.4667  132.2667      Australia      Australia     132.2667  -14.4667
South Pasadena         27.7526  -82.7394  United States  United States     -82.7394   27.7526
Beaconsfield           45.4333  -73.8667         Canada            NaN          NaN       NaN
Ferney-Voltaire        46.2558    6.1081         France            NaN          NaN       NaN
Jiangshan              28.7412  118.6225          China            NaN          NaN       NaN
Dīla                    6.4104   38.3100       Ethiopia            NaN          NaN       NaN
Gibara                 21.1072  -76.1367           Cuba            NaN          NaN       NaN
Hampstead              42.8821  -71.1709  United States  United States     -71.1709   42.8821
West Islip             40.7097  -73.2971  United States  United States   -160.41182  35.98157
Paulínia              -22.7611  -47.1542         Brazil            NaN          NaN       NaN
Saint-Basile-le-Grand      NaN       NaN            NaN         Canada     -73.2833   45.5333
Belokurikha                NaN       NaN            NaN         Russia      84.9833   52.0000
Finderne                   NaN       NaN            NaN  United States     -74.5743   40.5626
Belorechensk               NaN       NaN            NaN         Russia      39.8667   44.7667
Botucatu                   NaN       NaN            NaN         Brazil     -48.4450  -22.8858
Kibiti                     NaN       NaN            NaN       Tanzania      38.9500   -7.7296
```

Finaly from the concatenated df3 you can get rows where latitudes and longitudes in df2 don't match the City name in df1 :

```
df3[(df3['lat']!=df3['lat2']) & (df3['lng']!=df3['lng2'])].dropna()

                    lat      lng        country       country2         lng2      lat2
city                                                                             
West Islip  40.7097 -73.2971  United States  United States   -160.41182  35.98157
```

To find cities in df2 that are "located" in the wrong country :

```
 df3[df3['country']!=df3['country2']]
```